# gcc/ld ignored full relro options

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ld

I'm trying to compile a full RELRO program on my OpenSUSE 13.2.
With the following command

```
$ gcc a.c -z,relro,-z,now -o a
```

I got the warning:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: warning: -z ,relro,-z,now ignored.
```

And the generated binary is still partial RELRO.

My `gcc` and `ld` versions are:

```
gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.8.3 20140627 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 212064]
GNU ld (GNU Binutils; openSUSE 13.2) 2.24.0.20140403-6.1
```

What's wrong with my `gcc`?

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/143189/how-to-enable-relro-support

Comment: The `gcc` command doesn't have a `-z` option, do you mean e.g. `-Wl,-z,relro`?

Comment: if I compile with `-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now`, I will get no warnings.But the output binary `a` is still partial RELRO.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
gcc -m32 -g -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -o test test.c
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.